# Adding a local database to angular 10

Tags: angular, angular10

I am making a simple login app. Til now, I have made an app and made just 2 users (1 normal user ad 1 admin user), but it's basically hardcode. It looks like this now (in my authentication service):

```
private readonly mockedUser = new SignInData('user1', '123');
private readonly mockedAdmin = new SignInData('admin1', '456');
```

I tied the above to another file, my SignInData, which looks like this:

```
import { StringifyOptions } from 'querystring';

export class SignInData {
    private userID: string;
    private password: string;

    constructor(userID: string, password: string){
        this.userID = userID;
        this.password = password;
    }

    getUserID(): string
    {
        return this.userID;
    }

    getPassword(): string
    {
        return this.password;
    }
}
```

Now I wanna upgrade this to a local database, so new users (either normal users or admins) can be added and so everyone can login with their own username and password. How do I setup a local database?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a local database with firebase which is a cloud hosted NOSQL database. Here is the sample application set up.[Angular-Firebase setup](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/28/build-crud-app-with-angular-and-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IndexedDB with Angular.
IndexedDB is a local database that lives in your browser.
Here is a link to the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb)
And a link to a [small tutorial](https://mdbootstrap.com/education/pwa/angular/lesson-6-creating-indexeddb-database/) to get you started